# Can't download reviewed Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, add-on

Received the message below from Mozilla AddOn editors with regards to our new version of our add on:

"Your add-on, iGive Button 5.0.0.9, has been reviewed and is now signed and ready for you to download at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/igive-button-1/versions."

When I go to that link, I'm supposed to be able to download the reviewed and now signed add on.  To try to do that, I clicked on the link which lets me manage the add on.  At the top of the Manade Add On screen there is a link to the file (igive_button-5.0.0.9-fx.xpi):  https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/352648/igive_button-5.0.0.9-fx.xpi?src=devhub

However, when I click that link I get a "404 Not Found" error.

How do I get the signed add-on so we can distribute it from our web site?

Comment: Was it an unlisted addon?

Comment: Yes, it is an unlisted addon.  But, that just means it isn't listed in the addon store.  We should still be able to download the signed version so we can distribute it ourselves.

Comment: The reason I asked was that I dont have access to unlisted addons so I cant check to see what is happening. If it was a listed addon, I could check it. You need to ask one of the admin reviewers to check it.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get in touch with the admin reviewers?

Answer (score 0):

Try for the sources in
about:config

and search for browser.dictionaries.download.url

verify the sources of the apps is correct

Answer (score 0):

Did Mozilla send you a link to your preliminarily approved addon?  When you click that link it takes you to developer hub.  Under current versions there should be a link to your reviewed addon.  Click that link to go to the management page for your addon.  Near the top of this page you should see an element called "files" with your extension file shown as a link.  You should be able to click that link to download your file.